# Kivy Progress-Bar will not update until after 100% completion

Tags: python, kivy, progress-bar, python-multithreading, kivy-language

Kivy's Progress-bar is only graphically updating once the function that is updating its internal values is fully finished (100% completion).  I am using it to update a database of names and values, and want it to show the progress of the update.

As per other similar problems, all the below methods have been tried and failed:

```
(Clock.schedule_interval,Clock.schedule_once,Clock.create_trigger,@mainthread,Clock.schedule_once(partial(func))
```

Their remnants can be seen in the commented out sections below

There is a button on another page that I press which triggers update_database().  update_database calls updateLoadingScreen to change the values on the progress bar and label of the numerical percent done.  In isolation, it appears this function works.  However, running it in the update_database() causes the UI updates to freeze, until it simply outputs 100% completion.  Clock.schedule_interval pauses until 100% is reached, both internally and externally to the update_database function, Clock.schedule_once also waits until 100% is reached before doing anything.  Clock.create_trigger appears to not call anything except when it is instantiated.  Functools partial() doesn't change any behaviors. @mainthread gives Error:'mainthread' is not defined.

It doesn't appear to be a timing issue, as 0.2 seconds is good enough for it to update values in other situations.  However, it really does appear to be locked into the process and unable to update the UI, even though the UI parameters are modified.

```py
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from functools import partial


class UpdatePage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        #This part puts the series into a pandas dataframe
        self.df=getAllSeries()
        self.allserieslen=len(self.df)

        self.progress_bar=ProgressBar(max=self.allserieslen-1,value=0)
        self.add_widget(self.progress_bar)

        self.progress_label=Label(text='0%')
        self.add_widget(self.progress_label)

        #self.update_progress_trigger = Clock.create_trigger(self.updateLoadingScreen(self.currentseries,self.serieslen),-1)


        #Clock.schedule_interval(lambda x:self.updateLoadingScreen(self.currentseries,self.serieslen),.2)
        #This works, in a vaccum



    def update_database(self):
        #screenupdate=Clock.schedule_interval(lambda x:self.updateLoadingScreen(self.currentseries,self.serieslen),.2)
        for rownum in range(self.serieslen):
            chapters,name=findSingleSeriesChapter(self.df.at[rownum, 'URL'])
            self.currentseries=rownum

            #failed ways to update the screen (including the schedule and unscedule above and below)
            self.updateLoadingScreen(self.currentseries,self.serieslen)
            #Clock.schedule_once(lambda x:self.updateLoadingScreen(self.currentseries,self.serieslen),0.2)
            #self.update_progress_trigger()
            #Clock.schedule_once(lambda x:partial(self.updateLoadingScreen(self.currentseries,self.serieslen)),0.2)
            print('loop done',self.currentseries)
        #Clock.unschedule(screenupdate)

    #@mainthread
    def updateLoadingScreen(self,rownum,serieslen):
        print("Event has been triggered")
        self.progress_bar.value=rownum
        #self.remove_widget(self.progress_bar)
        #self.add_widget(self.progress_bar)
        percentage=str(round((rownum)/(serieslen-1)*100,1))

        self.progress_label.text=f"{percentage}%"
        #self.remove_widget(self.progress_label)
        #self.add_widget(self.progress_label)
```

Comment: If your `UI` is freezing, that suggests that your `Update_database` method is running on the main thread. You should run anything that takes any not insignificant time in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Kivy code that updates the UI should run on the mainthread, else the app "freezes" till the current running action is done. Try adding the @mainthread decorator to your progress bar code

`from kivy.clock import mainthread`

Comment: It turns out I didn't have the import, so that would explain the "not defined" error.  I've added the @mainthread decorator to updateLoadingScreen and updateDatabase, and run it with this decorator on each individually, but no combination of this decorator and any of the methods mentioned above seems to unfreeze the UI